# Does the relation stand?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ two non-empty sets. Does it stand that $\mathcal{P}(A \times B)=\mathcal{P}A \times \mathcal{P}B $?

I have tried the following:

$$A=\{ \varnothing \}, B= \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing \} \}$$

$$ A \times B=\{ <\varnothing, \varnothing>, <\varnothing,\{ \varnothing \}>\}$$

$$ \mathcal{P}(A \times B) \text{ has } 2^2=4 \text{ elements, but } \mathcal{P}A \times \mathcal{P}B, \text{ has } 8 \text{ elements }.$$

So, the equality does not stand. Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: Looks right! In general, $|\mathcal{P}(A)| = 2^{|A|}$ and $|A \times B| = |A| \cdot |B|$, so $|\mathcal{P}(A \times B)| = 2^{|A| \cdot |B|}$ while $\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)| = 2^{|A|} \cdot 2^{|B|} = 2^{|A|+|B|}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All one can say is that you are right,since sets can not be equal if they do not have same cardinality(number of elements).

Thus in general it does not stand.

Also you could observe that on the left of your equation you have subsets of cartesian product,while on the left you have cartesian product of subsets.From that we can conclude for $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ it holds that $\{(x,y)\} \in P(A \times B) $ but since x and y are not subsets of A and B respectively then $\{(x,y)\}$ can not belong to  $P(A) \times P(B)$

You should be encouraged to explore basic questions since they usually provide methods for proving more complex theorems.